# Convert datetime field to just a date field in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I've seen a few answers to questions similar to mine but I cannot get them to work. I have several date fields in my query that return the date and time like such 7/1/2014 12:00:00 AM. Is there a way I can just have the fields show 7/1/2014?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
C.RECEIPTDATE,
(I.CLIENTID ||' - '||PO.CLIENTNAME) AS CLIENT,
D.INVOICEID,
D.SVCFROMDATE,
D.SVCTODATE,
D.SVCCODE
FROM M_EQP_ORDERS
WHERE.....
```

I basically would like to cut down the two date fields to the shorter date format minus the time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please mention the `DATA TYPE`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use to_char function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
to_char(C.RECEIPTDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
(I.CLIENTID ||' - '||PO.CLIENTNAME) AS CLIENT,
D.INVOICEID,
D.SVCFROMDATE,
D.SVCTODATE,
D.SVCCODE
FROM M_EQP_ORDERS
WHERE.....
```

Comment: This is useful, but not really an answer to the question posted. The conversion is to string, not to a date type as required.

Answer (score 16):

Just use the function TRUNC.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
TRUNC(C.RECEIPTDATE),
(I.CLIENTID ||' - '||PO.CLIENTNAME) AS CLIENT,
D.INVOICEID,
TRUNC(D.SVCFROMDATE),
TRUNC(D.SVCTODATE),
D.SVCCODE
FROM M_EQP_ORDERS
WHERE.....
```

Comment: `TRUNC` set the time part to `00:00`, so if now is `15:42` then after truncation it will be `00:00`

Comment: Also, `TRUNC` returned `DATA TYPE` ***depends*** on the data type of the column.

Answer (score 5):

***DEPENDS*** on the data type.

If the column is `DATE` data type, then, as suggested already, `TRUNC` would do the job to display. But, if your ***locale-specific NLS date settings*** are different, then you will still see the time portion as midnight.

Else, you need to use `TO_DATE` with proper `FORMAT` and apply `TRUNC` to it.

***update***

If you only want to display, use `TO_CHAR`, else, if you have a filter in your `WHERE` clause, then remember `TO_CHAR` doesn't return `DATE`, it converts it into literal.

Comment: IMHO, this is the most complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD') dateonly, sysdate datetime from dual;

DATEONLY   DATETIME
---------- -------------------
2014/09/26 2014-09-26 15:41:03
```

Comment: `TO_CHAR` doesn't return a `DATE`. It must be used only for display. Since OP has not mentioned his `WHERE` clause, we don't know if the filter is applied or not.

Comment: @LalitKumarB As you fairly noticed, OP didn't specify what he really needs. But since data stored in the database as number and he told that he needed to show a date value in the `YYYY/MM/DD` format, I can conclude that he needs to format the output.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't find anywhere OP mentioned `NUMBER` as the data type.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle date datatype always includes the time.

TRUNC will truncate the time to midnight, which you will need to do if you want to match the date parts of two datetimes. The time may still display, depending on how your client is configured, so use TO_CHAR with an appropriate format mask to display it whatever way you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
to_date(C.RECEIPTDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
(I.CLIENTID ||' - '||PO.CLIENTNAME) AS CLIENT,
D.INVOICEID,
D.SVCFROMDATE,
D.SVCTODATE,
D.SVCCODE
FROM M_EQP_ORDERS
WHERE.....
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE your_table
SET created = TRUNC(modified);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).