# Convert 11/22/2016 12:37:51 PM SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I remove the **time** portion of a datetime field in Oracle?  For example, I have `11/22/2016 12:00:00 PM` and I only need `11/22/2016`.

I have tried this code:

```
TO_CHAR (dt_col, 'HH24:MI:SS') trunc(hh24:MI:SS)
```

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show you best attempt to solve your problem. Requests for 
tutorials, research, trecommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: @Mureinik TO_CHAR (dt_col, 'HH24:MI:SS') trunc(hh24:MI:SS)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert datetime field to just a date field in SQL (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062132/convert-datetime-field-to-just-a-date-field-in-sql-oracle)

Comment: I think the question has been reworded such that it is on-topic.  However, I agree it is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062132/convert-datetime-field-to-just-a-date-field-in-sql-oracle so I'm not voting to reopen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just try casting it as a DATE:

```
SELECT CAST(YourTimestampField AS DATE) AS MyDateField
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, according to the info in the comments, that you have a `date` column, you could use the `to_char` function with the proper format:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dt_col, 'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM my_table;
```

Comment: any other method which can be useful in this case

Comment: @palkodi - Please explain why this answer doesn't solve your problem. What additional requirement do you have which merits "any other method"???